# Rename an inport and outport of Subsystem

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am parsing a text file with matlab and trying to create a Simulink model from Matlab.

```
new_system(link_NameValue);
add_block('simulink/Ports & Subsystems/Subsystem',[link_NameValue '/' link_NameValue]);
set_param(gcb,'Description',sprintf('%s ==> %s', link_SourceNameValue, link_TargetNameValue));
set_param('On_Off/On_Off/In1','Port number',link_SourcePortNameValue);
```

I would like to rename name of Input In1 and Output Out1 of the subsystem with some parsed value.
I have tried this but returned me :

```
Inport block does not have a parameter named 'Port number'
```

Tried also with 'port' instead of 'Port number' but returned me :

```
Port number specified in 'On_Off/On_Off/In1' is invalid.  Port numbers must be positive integer constants less than or equal to 65535.
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: If `Port` didn't work then what is the datatype and value of `link_SourcePortNameValue`?  Why does it not satisfy `Port numbers must be positive integer constants less than or equal to 65535`?

Answer (score 1):

The property you want is `Port`, not `Port number`.  See [Block-Specific Parameters](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/block-specific-parameters.html#mw_e98d6a6c-3e97-43ad-81bf-cc13b85d1787) for the common properties of all the blocks and their allowable values.